# How to extract variable name and value from string in python

Tags: python, variables, python-3.x

I have a string

```
data = "var1 = {'id': '12345', 'name': 'John White'}"
```

Is there any way in python to extract var1 as a python variable. More specifically I am interested in the dictionary variables so that I can get value of vars: id and name.python

Comment: Although using the exec() function in Python is discouraged, it would be the easiest way to do what you want: `exec("var1 = {'id': '12345', 'name': 'John White'}")`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the functionality provided by [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec)

```
>>> my_scope = {}
>>> data = "var1 = {'id': '12345', 'name': 'John White'}"
>>> exec(data, my_scope)
>>> my_scope['var1']
{'id': '12345', 'name': 'John White'}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate what `exec` is actually doing here?

Comment: `exec` is the builtin for dynamic execution of code, there's not much to say other than what's already documented.

Answer (score 2):

You can split the string with `=` and evaluated the dictionary using `ast.literal_eval` function:

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval(ata.split('=')[1].strip())
{'id': '12345', 'name': 'John White'}
```