# NLP :: Extract entities and their values from string in Python

Tags: python-2.7, parsing, nlp, key-value, string-parsing

I have a certain list/dictionary of fruits names like below:

```
fruits = ["Banana","Apples","Oranges"]
```

This is just a sample list, there can be many more fruits in it.
My input text looks like below:

```
text1 = " I want to 2 Apples and 3 Bananas"
text2 = " I need Apples 2, Bananas 5"
text3 = "want to have 1 orange"
```

I want to note that my input string is a free flowing text and hence doesn't follow **any certain format**.

**Problem**: I want to parse the string and get a table/list with what quantity of which fruit I have. The amount can be before or after the fruit. Below can be seen as output for input "*text1*" I want:

```
Apple   2

Banana  3
```

I have gone through similar problem statements in various links but there the input string has certain format which my problem doesn't.
Some of the links which I have gone through are:

[python: extracting variables from string templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42536406/python-extracting-variables-from-string-templates)

[How to extract variable name and value from string in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35144597/how-to-extract-variable-name-and-value-from-string-in-python)

[extracting key value pairs from a string containing escaped characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22359216/extracting-key-value-pairs-from-a-string-containing-escaped-characters)

[get python dictionary from string containing key value pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380992/get-python-dictionary-from-string-containing-key-value-pairs)

Comment: You have three banana in text1 but want 1 as output. Is it a typo?

Comment: Yes it is!! I will edit the question. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

If the data is totally unstructured but sentence, you might have to go the nlp route. But if you are okay with making some basic assumptions, you can try to get around it.

For example:

1) Does each fruit come with a numerical quantity?

2) Can you have other gibberish numbers in the string?

```
Example: 1 4 5 Apple 1
```

If you can enforce basic rules like one fruit comes with one number and that number is the closest number (before or after) then you can extract the positions of the numbers and fruits and then take the closest number starting from left.

```
text1 = " I want to 2 Apples and 3 Bananas" -> [2, Apple, 3, Banana]

text2 = " I need Apples 2, Bananas 5" -> [Apple, 2, Banana, 5]

text3 = "want to have 1 orange" -> [1, Orange]
```

Comment: Does each fruit come with a numerical quantity? - Yes

Answer (score 0):

See [here](https://github.com/dharm0us/grocery/blob/master/src/main/java/extraction/OrderItemExtraction.java).
Here this problem is solved with heavy regex usage.

Look at the [test](https://github.com/dharm0us/grocery/blob/master/src/test/java/OrderItemExtractionTest.java) file which gives you an idea what kind of sentences it can parse.

For e.g., this code can extract name and quantity of items from a given text like:

```
I want to buy 2 kg tomato and 1 kg potato.
Also add 500 gms ginger.
```